# Redis Sentinel - Unable to delete keys on any index other than zero

Tags: php, redis, sentinel

while trying to implement sentinel on redis ( 1 master, 2 slaves), I have been unable to delete keys stored on it.

Sentinel version : 6.2.0

I check for keys with exists() and then trigger delete on the keys.

`$redis->exists()` on keys does return true.
`$redis->del($key) ->` returns zero all the time. I have tried passing keys as an array and also as single key one by one. Neither of them worked.

**I have been able to perform deletion with exact same code on db Index 0. It doesn't work on any other index.**